# If I have to use float left for multiple divs in a row, is there a way to center them with the leftover space?

Tags: html, css

For my class I have to have 3 `div`s floated left in a row with the outer two half the size of the middle one. It's driving me crazy that the rows aren't centered on the page. Is there a way to center them without getting rid of the float?

I tried creating a container div with text-align just as a shot in the dark but that didn't work. All other research I've seen is to change the float to display but I have to use float so I can't do that.

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

div.cover {
  width: 20%;
}

div.author {
  width: 50%;
  font-family: calibri;
}

div.links {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <p class="inner">
    <img src="Images/Divergent.jpg"><br>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="author">
  <p class="inner" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <b>Divergent<br>Veronica Roth</b><br>
  </p>
</div>
<div class="links">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="link" onclick="parent.open('https://www.britannica.com/biography/Veronica-Roth')">
        https://www.britannica.com/biography/Veronica-Roth
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *All other research I've seen is to change the float to display but I have to use float* --> because it's the only way, centring and float aren't friends

Comment: *"I have to have 3 divs floated left in a row with the outer two half the size of the middle one."* - But that's not what your code actually does. 20% is not half of 50%

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct to wrap the 3 "columns" in a container div is correct. This allows you to use what is commonly referred to as the "clearfix" trick. Items that are "floated" are ignored by the normal box flow of the page which is why the container seems to collapse and ignore your floating contents.

Frustrating indeed!

This is the "clearfix":

```
div.container:after {
  content: ''; /* no content in this pseudo element */
  display: table; /* be 100% wide */
  clear: both; /* clear the previous floats */
}
```

The `:after` pseudo selector on the container is the same thing as putting an empty div as the last item in the container. By clearing the floats, the container will wrap around the floating items.

This is a hack... but it works! The entire web development community has used this to "fix" the difficulties inherent with using floats for years to create layouts before the advent of real layout systems like Flexbox and CSS Grid.

After the container clears the floating items inside, just set the widths so that they add up to 100% and you are good.

```css
div.container {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}

div.container:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

div.cover {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

div.author {
  width: 50%;
  font-family: calibri;
  float: left;
}

div.links {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cover">
    <p class="inner">
      <img src="Images/Divergent.jpg"><br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="author">
    <p class="inner" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <b>Divergent<br>Veronica Roth</b><br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="https://www.britannica.com/biography/Veronica-Roth">
          Veronica-Roth
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really enjoyed your attitude but sadly it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

```
div.container position:relative;
div.cover float:left;
div.autor  put inside tag align="center" 
div.links float:right;
```

or

```
div.autor margin:5%;
```

or

```
display:inline-block;
```

or you can use `text-align:center;` in css on the parent div and then `display:inline-block;` on each div inside the parent div

Comment: `align` attribute is not valid on a `div`